# Decorating all inherited methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, decorator, python-xarray

#### Context

I would like to subclass a class from a library (xarray) which has a huge API, and I can't modify the class upstream. This superclass (xarray.Dataset) is a general data storage class, which I want subclass to make it more specific to my use case by adding new attributes and methods, while retaining most of the API.
I also want to be able to further subclass my new class in case another user wants even more specific functionality.

I've tried various approaches (which I am happy to describe in detail), but I'm not sure whether my newest idea (decorating all inherited methods) is possible/a terrible one.

#### Problem

The reason I can't simply subclass like this:

```
class MyDataset(xarray.Dataset):
    def __init__(data, new_input)
        super.__init__(self, data)
        self.new_attribute = new_input

    def new_method(self)
        return self.new_attribute
```

Is because lots of the inherited xarray.Dataset methods return new instances of xarray.Dataset objects, which means I will lose my new attributes when performing common operations on my data structure using those methods. i.e.

```
ds = MyDataset(data, new_input)

# take the mean of my data over time, a common operation which uses an inherited method 
result_ds = ds.mean(dim=time)

# Now I will have lost my extra data
print(result_ds.new_attribute)  # will return either AttributeError or None depending on the implementation of the method
```

#### My proposed solution

I know that I want all the methods that would normally return an instance of `xarray.Dataset` to instead return an instance of `MyDataset`, and that to get `MyDataset` from `xarray.Dataset` I just need to tack on the `new_attribute` data. (which is stored privately in the instance of `MyDataset` whose method was called.)

Can I therefore write something in the `__init__` of `MyDataset` which decorates all methods which were inherited from `super()`, using a decorator which checks if the return value of the method is an instance of `xarray.Dataset`, and if so converts it to an instance of `MyDataset` using my extra data? That way I could do:

```
ds = MyDataset(data, new_input)

# use an inherited method
result_ds = ds.mean(dim=time)

# Extra data will still be there because the decorator added it on before returning it
print(result_ds.new_attribute)  # prints value of new_attribute
```

I guess the code would have to look something like:

```
class MyDataset(xarray.Dataset):
    def __init__(data, new_input):
       super().__init__(self, data)
       self.new_attribute = new_input

       # Apply decorator to all inherited methods
       for callable in super().__dict__:
           return_val_decorator(callable, self.new_attribute)

    def new_method(self)
       return self.new_attribute

def return_val_decorator(func, extra_data, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrapper(extra_data, *args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)

        # If return value is an xarray dataset then reattach data
        if isinstance(result, xarray.Dataset):
            return _attach_extra_data(result, extra_data)
        else:
            return result
    return wrapper
```

#### Question

Is this possible? What will happen if I try to further subclass `MyDataset`? Can I give all subclasses this behaviour by using a metaclass somehow? Is this just a terrible idea that will lead to incomprehensible code or buggy behaviour?

Comment: This might work, but at the moment you are discarding all the wrapped members

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure what you mean - should I be iterating over something other than `super().__dict__`?

Comment: @ThomasNicholas - Have you seen http://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/internals.html#extending-xarray?

Comment: You do nothing with the result of `return_val_decorator`

Comment: @jhamman, yes I have - I've tried that but I think any attributes added to the accessor also get lost when a Dataset method is used, is that not true?

Comment: @Caleth so I need to somehow replace the inherited method with the result of `return_val_decorator`?

Comment: @ThomasNicholas - it may be worth opening a xarray github issue describing your use case in detail. My initial thought is that you should be able to use the `attrs` dict on the Dataset object and an accessor to do much of what you are trying for here.

Comment: @jhamman - I actually did, it's [here](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2473). I think you're right about being able to use accessors and `attrs`, which is why I've submitted pull request [#2482](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/pull/2482) to xarray to allow `attrs` to always be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrapper the dataset function in your class. I'm not sure this would work for everything though. How you deal with namespace collisions could be a problem, since you don't have actual inheritance to help you.

```
class MyDataset:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.dataset = xarray.Dataset(*args, **kwargs)
    def new_method(self):
        pass # Do stuff here
    def __getattr__(self, func):
        refer = getattr(self.dataset, func)
        if callable(refer):
            return self._subclass_wrapper(refer)
        else:
            return refer
    def _subclass_wrapper(self, func):
        def _wrap_func(*args, **kwargs):
            data = func(*args, **kwargs)
            if isinstance(data, xarray.Dataset):
                my_new = self.copy()
                my_new.dataset = data
                return my_new
            else:
                return data
        return _wrap_func
```

In theory, this should act like an `xarray.Dataset`, except any `xarray.Dataset` functions that return a `xarray.Dataset` object should instead return a copy of the `MyDataset` object, with the `MyDataset.dataset` replaced with the new `xarray.Dataset`.

In practice I think that I'd probably handle whatever metadata I wanted to keep with the `xarray.Dataset` in some other way; this wouldn't be my first choice.